# Lipschitz on union of sets

Tags: metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ be lipschitz
on open sets $U_{1}, U_{2}\subseteq X$. Prove or disprove that $f$ is lipschitz on $U_{1}
\cup U_{2}$.

I first tried to prove it:
Fix some  $u_1 \in U_{1}$ and $u_2 \in U_{2}$ and $M \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
\left| f( u_{1} ) - f( u_{2}) \right| 
\leqslant M \cdot d( u_{1}, u_{2}).
\end{align*}
Now, for any two points $a \in U_{1}, \; b \in U_{2}$ we have
\begin{align*}
\left| f( a) - f( b) \right| 
&= \left| f( a) - f( u_{1}) + f( u_{1}) - f( b) \right| 
\\ 
&\leqslant 
 \left| f( a) - f( u_{1}) \right| +\left|   f( u_{1}) - f( u_{2}) + f( u_{2}) - f( b) \right| 
 \\
 &\leqslant 
 \left| f( a) - f( u_{1}) \right| +\left|   f( u_{1}) - f( u_{2})   \right|+
 \left| f( u_{2}) - f( b) \right| 
 \\
 & \leqslant L_{1}d( a, u_{1}) + M d( u_1, u_2) + L_{2}d( u_{2}, b)
.\end{align*}
At this point I don't know how to continue, so I'm starting to doubt whether this is actually true.

Comment: Let $X=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$, set $f(x)=0$ on $(0,1)$ and $f(x)=1$ on $(1,2)$. Then $f$ is Lipschitz on $U_1:=(0,1)$ and on $U_2:=(1,2)$ (with $M=0$) but $f$ is not Lipschitz on $X=U_1\cup U_2$, since $|f(1+t)-f(1-t)|/(2t)=1/(2t) \to \infty$ as $t \to 0+$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505237/bounded-gradient-implies-lipschitz-on-non-convex-set/4505243#4505243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $X=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}$, with the standard metric of the real numbers.

Then $U_1=\{1/(2n):n\in\mathbb N\}$ and
$U_2=\{1/(2n+1):n\in\mathbb N\}$ are open subsets of $X$.

Set
$f(1/n)=0$ if $n$ odd, and $f(1/n)=1$ if $n$ is even.

Then $f$ is Lipschitz when restricted on either $U_i$ but discontinuous!